# Making ajax request with Python not returning an intended response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, python-requests

Trying to make a same request implemented in Code **(1)** using python, which is a part of a backend data fetching process on an online card game card lookup website (https://splintx.com/). The intended response should contain two data (*date data*, and *price history data*) as shown in **(2)**.

How could I simulate this using python?
I tried it with **(3)** but the response only contains *date data*. It returns the *price history data* empty (see **(4)**).
Thanks.

#### (1) Code excerpt - [Github](https://github.com/forrest-fan/SplintX/blob/491e82b9b13a23a954cb09d042d45544aa60163d/src/Components/Market/MarketList/MarketCard/MarketCardModal/MarketCardModal.js#L390)

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.panel === 'forSale' && prevState.panel === 'multiSelect' && this.state.selected !== prevState.selected) {
            this.updateSort('selected');
        } else if (this.state.panel === 'history' && prevState.panel !== 'history') {
            let edition = this.props.info.edition === 'Alpha' ? 0 : this.props.info.edition === 'Beta' ? 1 : this.props.info.edition === 'Promo' ? 2 : this.props.info.edition === 'Reward' ? 3 : this.props.info.edition === 'Untamed' ? 4 : 5;
            let foilInt = this.props.info.gold ? 1 : 0;
            let id = this.props.info.detailID;
            let priceData = JSON.stringify([{
                id: id,
                foil: foilInt,
                edition: edition
            }]);
            let storageSearch = 'history-' + priceData;

            ...

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://splintx.com/db.php',
                    data: {card: priceData},
                    jsonpCallback: 'testing',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(history) {
                        let expiry = new Date();
                        expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 1);
                        expiry.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        let historyObj = {
                            expiry: expiry,
                            data: history
                        };
                        let storageName = 'history-' + priceData;
                        sessionStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(historyObj));
                        let prices = history[1];
                        let dates = history[0];
                        let newPrices = [];
                        let newDates = [];
                        ...
```

#### (2) Intended response (on Chrome Devtools->Application->Session Storage)

[image]

#### (3) Python code

```
import requests
res = requests.get(
    url='https://splintx.com/db.php',
    params={
        'card':
            {
                'id': 141,
                'foil': 0,
                'edition': 4,
            }

    },
)
```

#### (4) Unintended response - `response[1]` is supposed to have *price history data* but is empty

```
[["2020-08-24 12:00:01am","2020-08-25 12:00:01am","2020-08-26 12:00:01am", ...], []]
```

Comment: And what is the "un"-intended ajax response?

Comment: You haven't shown us "priceData" in the Javascript.  Is the API expecting a JSON-encoded string for the "card" parameter?  Because `requests` will not automatically JSON-encode your parameter.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks, added more code. It does apply ```json.stringify``` to the "card" parameter

Comment: It seems `priceData` in your JS is a string, but you are passing a dict in your python code. Also the JS version has an array around the object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are JSON-encoding your Javascript, you need to JSON-encode your Python as well:

```
import requests
res = requests.get(
    url='https://splintx.com/db.php',
    params={
        'card': json.dumps(
            {
                'id': 141,
                'foil': 0,
                'edition': 4,
            }
        )
    },
)
```

Comment: hmm even with the above code, I still receive the same response

Answer (score 0):

After a further debugging, I found that the `data: {card: priceData}` is actually sent as *Form Data*, not as *query string*. [(Differences between *Form Data* and *query string*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106669/formdata-vs-query-string)
*Form Data* is sent inside the HTTP body of a POST request, and with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986228/difference-between-using-requests-get-and-requests-session-get), I have realised the below working code.

Not quite sure why *Session* should be created upfront when dealing with *Form Data* yet.

```
import requests

pricedata = '[{"id":141,"foil":0,"edition":4}]'
data = {'card': pricedata}

session = requests.Session()
req = session.post('https://splintx.com/db.php', data=data)

print(req.content)
```